# Why no push/pop in front of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In C++, STL, we have template class `<vector>`.
We know that it supports `O(1)` random access, and tail modification.
My question is why we don't define push_front, or pop_front in `<vector>`?

One explanation is that if we want to push/pop element in the front of a vector, we must shift each element in the array by one step and that would cost `O(n)`.

But I think that is not always the case. Considering that if we implement `<vector>` with circular array, we can achieve `O(1)` push/pop from both front and tail of the vector, without losing the ability of `O(1)` random access. So personally I can not think of any reason rather than just a minor overhead not to implement `push_front`/`pop_front` for `<vector>`. Any thoughts?

Comment: It was designed the way it is. End of story.

Comment: And the overhead of the calculations needed to handle the circular buffer are not worth thinking about? It's not always about O(), it's about the actual real world performance also.

Comment: We cannot define the std::vector as circular, due to limitations set by the standard.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to make it easy to mis-use containers.  You can make your own if you really must.   It's not hard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> One explanation is that if we want to push/pop element in the front of a vector, we must shift each element in the array by one step and that would cost O(n)

You are absolutely right, `push_front` has no way to run quickly, because, in addition to a possible reallocation, all items need to be copied by one position. This gives you an amortized performance of O(n<sup>2</sup>) for n objects, which is not something that library designers wanted to encourage.

> Considering that if we implement `<vector>` with circular array

Implementing vector with circular array makes it a lot harder to implement several important guarantees that must be true for a vector. For example, vector must guarantee that if iterator `a` points to an element with a lower index than iterator `b`, then `a < b`. When vector is linear, the comparison boils down to comparing addresses of elements to which iterators `a` and `b` are pointing. With a circular array implementation one would need to take the address of the vector origin into consideration, which can now be in the middle of the allocated block of memory.

Another guaranteed that would be violated is this:

> When `v` is a `vector<T>`, `T` is any type other than `bool`, and `n` a number between zero and vector's size, `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` identity must be true.

This cannot be implemented with a circular array.

Comment: I think comparing of iterators can actually be quite easy to implement.
For instance we can take remainder of the distance between a specific pointer to begin pointer, and just compare that remainder. Does that cause problems in implementation?

Comment: @TaylorHuang It can certainly be implemented, but it pushes vector farther away from being a good array replacement. By design, vectors offer an extremely low overhead; circular arrays are close in terms of performance, but still not free. To library designers, a flexibility to add elements to the front did not justify making any performance sacrifices.

Comment: Oh okay, and also this violates some protocols as well, I think I wasn't thinking quite neat.

Answer (score 13):

We already have something as you describe in the STL. It is named `deque`.

As you wrote there IS actually some overhead. So if you need this functionality and you have no problem with the overhead, use `deque`. If you do not require it, you do not want the overhead, so it is better to have something that avoids this overhead, named `vector`.

And as an addition: `vector` guarantees that all its elements are stored in contiguous storage locations, so you can apply pointer arithmetic. This is not the case for a circular buffer.

Comment: Oh I think indeed deque is what I was looking for.
I used to think deque do not support O(1) random access, I guess I was wrong. :)

Comment: Okay thank you.
I think this was helpful, but @dasblinklight pointed out lots of my flaws so I guess I'll select his as accepted, but yours are also helpful. :)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this *is* a realistic requirement. To my knowledge, nothing in the standard mandates that the vector cannot have a buffer *before* the elements (`v.prefix_capacity()`), just as *after* (`v.capacity() - v.size()`). This could guarantee the same runtime for `v.push_front()` and `v.push_back()`, while not having any cost for those who don't use it. Additionally, it could guarantee O(1) `v.pop_front()`, albeit by invalidating iterators. Fancy writing a proposal?

In the meanwhile, you might create a template (`devector`?) in terms of vector, which:

- has a field `pre_capacity_` initialized to 0 and a getter `pre_capacity()`
- implements `pre_reserve(size_t i)` which calls both:

  - `reserve(capacity() - pre_capacity_ + i)`
  - `pre_capacity_ += i`
- implements `operator[](size_t i)` and delegates to `v[i + pre_capacity()]`
- implements `at(size_t i)` and delegates to `v.at(i + pre_capacity())`
- implements `begin()` and delegates to `v.begin() + pre_capacity()`
- delegates all the rest of the methods to `vector`

Or you can just track the number of elements you've pushed to / popped from front :).

Comment: I think such generic container would be helpful, like 'deque' isn't it? :)
But what about such protocol:
'''
    When v is a vector<T>, T is any type other than bool, and n a number between zero and vector's size, &v[n] == &v[0] + n identity must be true.
'''
With  buffer before element, how can such guarantee be fulfilled?

Comment: I have such a data structure in the works, called [devector](https://github.com/orlp/devector). The implementation isn't finished yet though (I should really finish it someday).

Comment: @TaylorHuang: note that `push_front()` invalidates iterators. Thus `&v[0]` can decrease when you `push_front()` w/o reallocation. Think of it this way: the reallocation is done `sizeof(T)` bytes before current buffer.

Comment: I suppose without reallocation, the iterator will still be valid after push_front(), won't it? For instance, if we have
`iterator iter=&v[0];`
`v.push_front();`
`cout<<(*iter);`
We still get unchanged element if w/o reallocation.

Comment: @TaylorHuang: with no reallocation, the iterator will point to the same value (not the same position). NB. you always call `vector::reserve()` from `devector::push_front()`; therefore you can't tell if there was a reallocation.

Comment: @lorro Okay, I see. But does that cause a problem? I mean, is it regulated by standard that an iterator must always points to the same index if there ain't any reallocation? It seems to make sense for iterator to stay in the same address as well.
By the way , just curious, what is the difference between your so-called `devector` and `deque`? They seem to be the same.

Comment: @TaylorHuang: `deque` does not warrant continuous allocation of members. A popular implementation of `deque` is vector of array, all except the last array having the same number of elements. `vector` is nice because it's continuous; in fact, `v.data()` or `&v[0]` is a variable-length array. We want to keep that property; all it costs is a `size_t` per `vector`.

Comment: Oh okay. It seems possible. But now the question is why such feature do not appears in `<vector>`?

Comment: @TaylorHuang: hence I suggested to have a proposal. It'd cost at most 1 `size_t`; however, if you commit to not having more than e.g. 1/4 of the memory allocated for the same vector (may I say, a wise commitment), then you can use those bits to signal the ratio (like, 0:1, 1:16, 1:1, 16:1) of `capacity()` and `pre_capacity()`. With that said, I'd just go for adding one `size_t`...

Comment: Boost now has devector implementation: [boost::container::devector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost/container/devector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a de-vector introduces 2 challenges:

- Retaining O(1) random access (unlike: deque).
- O(1) push operation, to either side (front or back), which's the benefit of deque.

Both are achievable, in the following manner:

- Implement a devector class, which publicly inherits from std::vector. Hence we have the std::vector API available, and "just" need to override the methods which require overriding.
- The inherited vector (base class) will be utilized for regular push_back insertions.
- The devector class will also have a private std::vector member, let's refer it as *front_insertions*.
- Any push_front to the devector, will perform push_back to *front_insertions* (the private member vector).
- Size of devector will be the sum of both sizes: the inherited vector, and the size of *front_insertions*.
- Random access to an element of index i, will be implemented in the following manner:
  If *front_insertions* is empty, we just reuse the inherited random access method as-is. Else if i < *front_insertions.size()* we access *front_insertions[front_insertions.size() - 1 - i]*. Else, we access *[i - front_insertions.size()]* of the inherited vector.
- Obviously, some other std::vector methods can be overriden, such as emplace_back, emplace_front, at, etc'. I focused on retaining both O(1) random access, and push to either side.