# Range based for loop: Iterate over vector extended with one element

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, range

I want to achieve more less the equivalent to this Python code in C++ (but more memory efficient):

```
a = [1, 5, 3]
additional = 6
for elem in [additional] + a:
    print(elem) # prints: 6 1 5 3

# alternative without creating the additional vector:
import itertools
for elem in itertools.chain([additional], a):
    print(elem)
```

The only way that I know to do this in C++ is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
        std::vector<int> a = {1, 5, 3};
        int additional = 6;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.size() + 1; ++i) {
                int cur_elem;
                if (i == 0) {
                        cur_elem = additional;
                } else {
                        cur_elem = a[i-1];
                }
                std::cout << cur_elem << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with a range based for loop? I found the Boost join operator but it seems to use only iterables, so I need to create an extra vector (like in the Python example).

Ideally, the iteration would be without creating the joined object in the memory and with algorithms of the standard library.

Comment: Why not just print it before the loop?

Comment: Whenever you want to do unusual things in an range based for loop, you can always write a custom iterator type to do whatever you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why no push/pop in front of vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052040/why-no-push-pop-in-front-of-vector) Basically, `push_front()` appends to the start of a collection, but you should be using an `std::list` instead of a `vector`.

Comment: @KenY-N Valid reasons for `std::list` are rare. Basically, unless iterator/reference invalidation rules are very important for your application, there is probably a better container than `std::list`. Here, it's `std::deque`.

Comment: @KenY-N additionally, he mentions that he wants to avoid creating a new container just for the sake of iterating, and I agree with him. In fact, one of the selling points of the new ranges library is being able to do this easily. (My point is that I don't think this is a duplicate of the mentioned question)

Comment: @CássioRenan The Python example uses a list rather than a vector, so changing the declaration of `a` to use an `std::deque` seems more in keeping with the original code, and `push_front()` doesn't create an additional container but then again making `a` a `const` is even more in spirit with the original Python, so we would need to make a copy before pushing... Anyway, nice answer!

Comment: @KenY-N you're right, I misinterpreted the "without creating the joined object" part. And yeah, I agree making the container `const` (and thus unable to be changed by - for instance - adding elements to it) makes the C++ code more analogous to the provided python snippets.

Comment: @GBlodgett This is possible in the MWE. In my real code the loop body is much bigger. Of course, it would also work to lay this out in a function and call this function twice: before and in the loop. However, I find the solution to increase the element of the iterator cleaner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done using the upcoming ranges feature.

Here's an example using Eric Niebler's `range-v3` library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/single.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 5, 3};
    int additional = 6;
    for (auto i : ranges::concat_view(ranges::single_view{additional}, a)) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

### [See it live!](https://godbolt.org/z/xW6FWx)

by using views, all iterator operations are lazy, and no extra memory is used (e.g.: no extra vectors/arrays are created)

Or, without the `for` loop:

```
ranges::copy(ranges::concat_view(ranges::single_view{additional}, a), ranges::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ","));
```

### [See it live!](https://godbolt.org/z/gT8Ae5)

*(Honestly, I like the `for` version better, though)*

### Standard-compliant solution

There's a small issue with the solution above: `concat_view` did not make it into C++20. If you want a strictly compliant solution, you may want to create your own version, or use `join_view` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 5, 3};
    int additional = 6;

    std::vector v{{additional}, a};

    for(int i : std::ranges::join_view{v}) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, my loop body is not just a print, therefore the explicit loop is nicer. Do you know, why concat_view did not make it and if it may come in future versions?

Comment: @gerion It was simply not part of the initial proposal. `ranges-v3` is already huge as it is, so adding the whole library at once to the standard was(is) not feasible. Eric does mention in his [blog](http://ericniebler.com/2018/12/05/standard-ranges) (look at the "Future Directions" section at the end) that he may propose to add it in the future along with several other adaptors, but I don't know when (or if) that will be.